# Why PhpStorm icon is not visible in the task manager line?

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm

After moving to PhpStorm 2021.1 under Kubuntu 18 I lost PhpStorm icon.
I tried to apply it in KDE Menu Editor, but PhpStorm icon is shown in favorite of system menu, but not in task manager line:

How can it be fixed?

[image]

Comment: You can try to re-create the icon via _Tools | Create Desktop Entry_.

Comment: Is it option in Storm IDE? I did not find it... Also I did not find sinilar option in KMenuEdit

Comment: Here is a similar report:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149703

Unfortunately, there is no solution though :(